# Data loss exporting shapefile to CSV in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv

I have a points shapefile with numerous attributes for each point that I'm exporting to CSV using Layer > Save As... in QGIS A Coruña (3.10). Then I selected Comma Separated Values [CSV] and exported no problem.

Downstream in my analysis in R I then encountered problems specifically with the Date_Time field that had had the seconds cropped from the time stamp in this field. I traced the issue back to the csv export process where this information was being excluded/truncated/rounded somehow.

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate what your question is?

Answer (score 1):

After playing with options in the Save Vector Layer As... export menu, I closed the 'Select fields to export and their export options' drop-down menu, and then re-opened it.

[image]

[image]

Somehow a previously hidden/invisible option to 'Replace all selected raw field values by displayed values' suddenly appeared being ticked as the default option.

When this option was ticked, the fidelity of the export was as might be expected and this was causing the truncation of the seconds from the Date_Time field in the exported data. When unticked the raw data values were exported completely, including the second values also as might be expected. There is no problem with the functionality of this option, but the problem comes from the fact that this option is invisible at first in the 'Save Vector Layer as...' menu. It would not be intuitive to close and open the drop-down to access additional options and can easily be missed, potentially causing problems in the exported CSV data when not anticipated. If you have CSV output data that is not as expected or truncated as display data might be, then this could be the problem, easily resolved, but hard to find. I don't know if this has been updated in later versions of QGIS.

[image]

Comment: I can confirm the behaviour in QGIS 3.26.1-Buenos Aires on Win10. Seems to be a bug, you should report it.